# How can I go to a specific QWizard page number?

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qwizard, qwizardpage

`Qt 5`, [QWizard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html)

Hello! I have checked some answers on that subject but still can't quite figure that out. Here is the idea that I want to do:

I want to create a button group navigate between `QWizard` pages.

For example, at the top of my `QWizard` I have:

[image]

On button click, I get an id, the same as pages id, and I want to show the user page with this id.

I try to call:

```
this->page(pageId)->show();
```

Of course, it's not correct! I see `addPage(), page(), and pageAdded().` but it is has not set method.

Сertainly I can analyze my id, get current page number, and called `this->back();` or `next` method, but maybe it has the simplest method, that I don't know?

```
void StartupWizard::OnPageNumMove(int pageIdToMove)
{
    if(currentId()==pageIdToMove)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if(currentId()<pageIdToMove)
        {
            while (pageIdToMove!=currentId())
            {
                this->next();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (pageIdToMove!=currentId())
            {
                this->back();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Qt 6.4.2 you can call [QWizard::setCurrentId](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.4/qwizard.html#setCurrentId) to

> Set currentId to id, without visiting the pages between currentId and id.